# How to add MediatR PublishStrategy to existing project

Tags: c#, .net-core, mediatr

Now I use MediatR notifications like this:

```
private readonly IMediator _requestsRouter; // from constructor injection 

 OrderCreatedEvent orderCreatedEvent = new OrderCreatedEvent(x,y,z);
 await _requestRouter.Publish(orderCreatedEvent);
```

I would like to change default [PublishStrategy](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#publish-strategies) to  `ParallelNoWait = 3,`

Question: How to extend MediatR functionality from nuget with MediatR  PublishStrategies from [sample](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/tree/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.PublishStrategies) ?

I understand that I can download MediatR source code, add  to it code from MediatR.Examples.PublishStrategies and build my own library but maybe there is another "fast" way?

Answer (score 2):

You could extend `Publish` creating a subclass defining your own `DefaultStrategy`:

```
public class MyPublisher : Publisher
{
    public MyPublisher(ServiceFactory serviceFactory) : base(serviceFactory)
    {
        DefaultStrategy = PublishStrategy.ParallelNoWait;
    }
}
```

So you keep the source code intact from Mediatr by calling the base constructor and overriding the value with which the `DefaultStrategy` member was initialized.

And, of course, register your custom `MyPublisher` in your DI Container instead of `Publisher`:

```
services.AddSingleton<MyPublisher>();
```

Comment: Thanks! But do I still need to add code and compile from samples/MediatR.Examples.PublishStrategies to use `PublishStrategy.ParallelNoWait` ?

Comment: also I have no `DefaultStrategy` in namespace MediatR (`using MediatR;`)

Answer (score 2):

You cant set any PublishStrategy anymore, instead you will have to do the following:

1. Use the MediatR DI extensions package
2. create a new custom class, inherit from Mediator, override the PublishCore method and add whatever behaviour you want. By default the implementation is a foreach and await of each handler.
3. Specify the implementation type in startup.cs

services.AddMediatR(opt => opt.Using< myCustomMediatorType >(), typeof(Program));

Answer (score 0):

If the intended solution is to fire and forget, a much simpler solution is not awaiting when you publish. This also expresses the intent of your code better, as having await, but skipping is kind of misleading.